# What is the bar on the left showing in Konsole?

Tags: kde5, konsole

I mean this thing:

[image]

This is not the scrollbar (which is on the other side of the window). It seems to show the output of the last command run, but if I scroll back it seems to show "random" lines. The best explanation to its behavior is that it groups outputs that have been produced within a short time of each other but this only applies to the last command.

This appeared when I upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04 (so running Konsole 21.12.3 now).

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related to the option "Highlight lines coming into view" that you can set under "Scrolling" when you create a new profile:

[image]

It's not available to change in the default profile as that's not writable, so you only see that option when creating a new profile.

Comment: Looks like that's it. Thx.